# Effect Advanced CSS3, custom border to image

Tags: css, jquery-effects

I want to know if you do this effect with CSS possible?

That is an image edge and separated with css values​​.

Border rounded and prevention image suits.

Have any idea, someone has done, please comment.

**Image Example:** http://i40.tinypic.com/14vk4ti.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could type an explanation but [this is a much better (and prettier)](http://css-tricks.com/understanding-border-image/) resource.

Enjoy.